# Asp.Net Core - appsettings.json Dictionary<string, Value> property mapping is not working in Azure environment

Tags: c#, azure, dictionary, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have gone through a couple of similar questions in SO but both are not working as expected in the Azure environment.

I have the following `appsettings.json` configuration

```
  {
"Luis": {
    "SubDomain": {
        "AreaOne": {
            "AppIds": {
                "Us": "12345678",
                "India": "567890"
            },
            "APIKey": "xyz123",
            "HostName": "www.example.com"
        },
          "AreaTwo": {
            "AppIds": {
                "Us": "12345679",
                "India": "887890"
            },
            "APIKey": "xyz456",
            "HostName": "www.exampleareatwo.com"
        }
    }
}
}
```

We are trying to bind it to the following object

```
public class Luis
{
    public Dictionary<string,SubDomain> SubDomainLuis { get; set; }
}
public class SubDomain
{
    
    public Dictionary<string, string> AppIds { get; set; }
    public string APIKey { get; set; }
    public string HostName { get; set; }
}
```

We are getting the proper result in the local environment but after hosting the azure app service it shows as `null` value.

**This is the constructor code:**

The `LuisConfig.SubDomainLuis` is always returning a null value in the azure environment.

```
var LuisConfig = new Luis();
ConfigurationBinder.Bind(configuration.GetSection(nameof(Luis)), LuisConfig);
```

**Startup class:**

```
var config = new Luis();
        Configuration.Bind("Luis", config);
        services.AddSingleton(config);
```

The directory is always copying the settings file.

[image]

These are the questions I have already referred.

1. [Dictionary issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694791/map-appsettings-json-to-dictionarystring-value)
2. [appsettings mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846296/how-to-load-appsetting-json-section-into-dictionary-in-net-core)
3. [Configuration binding doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426386/configuration-binding-doesnt-work)

Comment: In your screenshot the file is `appsettings.DEV.json`, I guess your app in azure runs in Production environment.

Comment: You are absolutely right @ChristianHeld !! I missed out environment variable in azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChristianHeld mentioned in the comment the issue is related to the environment `appsettings.json`. We forget to add environment variable details in the azure configuration. So that is the reason it always points to `appsettings.json` instead of `appsettings.Local.json` or `appsettings.Dev.json`.

`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is the environment key and value you can add as UAT, DEV, Prod, etc.

Azure AppService -> Configuration

[image]